# Dynamic Authorizer on other realm on crosbar.io

Tags: wamp, crossbar

I'm currently using Crossbar , and i want to put my dynamic authentifier and authorizer in a protected realm for security reason .
There is an option like : "authenticator-realm : realm " for Authorizer ?

Answer (score 0):

Crossbar doesn't have that feature today, so you need to build a custom solution yourself. Also try reporting a bug on our github as a feature request.

I believe what you are trying to do could be achieved by creating a separate [realm](https://crossbar.io/docs/Router-Realms/) in your router configuration and then add configuration for your [authenticator](https://crossbar.io/docs/Router-Components/) in crossbar config.

Your main realm (non-authenticating) could then add another authenticator that verifies some kind of token obtained from the first authenticator.

Obviously that's just an idea, you can probably figure out better solutions.

Comment: Thank you , for your response , i made multiple authorizer for each of my realm. That's better because it divide all the work between multiple process.